# Custom WooCommerce message/notice at checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to display a custom message/notice at the WooCommerce checkout page for logged out users only. I would like the message to appear every time a non logged in user enters the checkout page and have a button/link inside the notice that would hide it.

Here's an example on [fiverr.com](https://www.fiverr.com/):

[image]

How can this be achieved?

---

**EDIT:**

```js
$('.hide-notice').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('.checkout-notice').slideUp("slow", function() {
    $(this).parents('.checkout-notice').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.woocommerce-info {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class="checkout-notice">
  <div class="woocommerce-info">
    Custom message custom message custom message custom message.
    <a href="" class="hide-notice">Hide message</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `woocommerce_before_checkout_form` to add a custom message. check the below code. code goes in your active theme function.php file.

Add CSS as per your requirement.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'add_custom_message_to_checkout', 1 );
function add_custom_message_to_checkout() {

    if( !is_user_logged_in() ){

        echo '<div class="custom-checkout-message">This is custom checkout message. you can add CSS as per your requirement. <a href="" class="hide-me">close me</a></div>';
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){
                $('.hide-me').on('click',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent('.custom-checkout-message').fadeOut(300, function() { 
                        $(this).parent('.custom-checkout-message').remove(); 
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
        <?php
        
    }
}
```

**Tested and works.**

[image]

```js
$('.hide-me').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.custom-checkout-message').fadeOut(300, function() { 
        $(this).parent('.custom-checkout-message').remove(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-checkout-message">This is custom checkout message. you can add CSS as per your requirement. <a href="" class="hide-me">close me</a></div>
```

Comment: This notice will be shown to everyone and not just to users who are not logged in.

Comment: Try adding the check with `! is_user_logged_in()`.

Comment: @VincenzoDiGaetano Updated. Thanks for the notice. I forgot to add.

Comment: Hi @Bhautik, thank you for your answer, it works great. The only thing is that the `.slideUp` animation is a bit laggy. It slides up to about the middle of the message and the randomly disappears [(Screen recording)](https://streamable.com/5jxw0j).  Why is it not smooth and is it possible to fix it?

Comment: do you want to disappear message?

Comment: @Bhautik, yes, I want the message to disappear after clicking the `hide-me` link but I'd like the disappearing animation to be smooth and as you can see in [this screen recording](https://streamable.com/5jxw0j), it's not smooth. Do you know why? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Your given screen recording link not working. do you have any examples?

Comment: @Bhautik, how about this link: https://files.fm/f/7yj4zb8wt

Comment: @Bhautik, I like the previous `slideUp` animation more, I just want to fix the jerkiness of it. I suspect that the issue might be caused by the margins and paddings I have applied to the message. Is it possible to wrap the whole message into another `<div>` and apply the JS to it?

Comment: Please create a snippet in your question.

Comment: @Bhautik, I added a code in my original question. The link does not work because I wrapped the whole message into another `<div>`. Could you fix the JS so that it affects the outer `<div>`?

Comment: @Bhautik, I think I've figured it out. I changed `.parent` to `.parents` so the jQuery targets the outer `<div>` and it works great on my website with no lag at all. Thank you for your help.